# Evaluation error

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets which I am working with here.  sheet1 which the user will press this button from, contains a column called "Cabinet date" which is just a list of dates that relate to each report.
Sheet2 (Deadlines) contains also the cabinet date column, matched with a series of deadlines to be met before this date (in the same row).
//for example the deadline of any draft report in January cabinet would be in the same row.//

I want to make a button that when pressed will find the cabinet date in sheet2 which matches the one in the active cell (on sheet1), as well as pick up the heading which it was under (the searchCol), then return the exact deadline value for that event in the correct cabinet date from sheet2.

The problem I have currently is that when I run this button it seems to not pick up the cabinet date value from sheet2, and cause  the annotated line to evaluate to nothing/true and skip the block of code which would print the deadline date.

All Im getting when I press this is "deadline not found". even when there is in fact a value it should pick up.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cabDate As String, findme As Range
Dim searchCol As Integer

searchCol = ActiveCell.Column
cabDate = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A1:O9999"), ActiveCell.Row, 2)

If Not IsEmpty(cabDate) Then
    With Worksheets("Deadlines").Range("B:B")
        Set findme = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cabDate, Sheets("Deadlines").Range("A1:O9999"), 1, False)
        If Not findme Is Nothing Then
            Dim findmeAddr As String
            findmeAddr = findme.Address(True, True)
            Dim printable As String
            printable = findme.Offset(0, searchCol).Value
            MsgBox (printable)
        Else
            MsgBox ("Deadline not found")
        End If
    End With
Else
    MsgBox ("invalid or non existent cabinet date")
End If
End Sub
```

Not all that experienced with coding so any help at all would be appreciated

Edit:
[image: made up some data as the I work with confidential data]

Answer (score 2):

You mixed-up a little between all the different types of variables, and what type each function returns.

`WorksheetFunction.Index` - returns a value of a certain cell (or range of cells), so you need to define `cabDate As String`.
So instead of using `If Not cabDate Is Nothing Then` (since it's not a `Range`) you need to use `If Not IsEmpty(cabDate) Then`.

The `Find` method using the `Set findme` returns a `Range`, so you can't later on also use it with `findme = findme.Address(True, True)` , but you need to define another variable `As String` and then you can read the `String` address to it.

And last, since you want to read a value from `printable`, it needs to be `As String` or `As Integer`, but not a `Range`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cabDate As String, findme As Range
Dim searchCol As Integer

searchCol = ActiveCell.Column
cabDate = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A1:O9999"), ActiveCell.Row, 2)

If Not IsEmpty(cabDate) Then
    With Worksheets("Deadlines").Range("B:B")
        Set findme = .Find(what:=cabDate)

        If Not findme Is Nothing Then
            Dim findmeAddr As String
            findmeAddr = findme.Address(True, True)

            Dim printable As String                
            printable = findme.Offset(0, searchCol).Value
            MsgBox (printable)
        Else
            MsgBox ("Deadline not found")
        End If
    End With
Else
    MsgBox ("invalid or non existent cabinet date")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for that I have made the changes :) However I am still getting that code block skip in the same place now, I think that it may have something to do with my data structure or the range i set in 'With' as when i use the .Find method to search sheet2, a blank cell is being referenced rather than the cell which contains the matching data.

Comment: @Dingge like i wrote above, sharing how your data structure in your worksheet looks like will help us help you

Comment: There you go, Left is the sheet people will search deadlines from, using that button i want them to be able to press it on an active cell and retrieve the deadline from sheet2

Comment: You might have a problem with cell format consistency since you are using a Date, it might be formatted in a different way

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Set findme = .Find(what:=cabDate, lookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)
```

since `Find()` method of `Range` object remembers the last settings of those parameters even if made from Excel UI

and be sure that `ActiveCell` is what you're actually expecting it to be!

Comment: Still getting the same skip, I will try messing around with the data types here maybe, thank you for the help

Comment: I wouldn't say data types are the culprit, rather step through your code and check for `ActiveCell` to be what you actually expect it to be

Comment: Ive been using msgbox and the debugger notifications to show me that the variables are being picked up correctly. So far cabDate seems to print fine no matter where i place the active cell, it gives me the correct cabDate from sheet1.  It seems the problem im having now is actually getting the program to locate an exact match on sheet2, I keep getting 'findme = nothing' in the debugger, Ive tried using Vlookup as well but this also cant find the matching value.

Comment: are dates really dates? I mean if you query `?cabDate.Value` what do you get returned?

Comment: so `Set cabDate = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A1:O9999"), ActiveCell.Row, 2)` isn't working as expected, is it?

Comment: Why does the messagebox show me the correct value?  Isnt that because i set cabDate to a string and .value needs a range?

Comment: in your code I see `Dim cabDate As Range`. If you dimmed it to a `String` then type `?cabDate`

Comment: Ah, I will update the original code, apologies. Now i get 'object doesn't support this property or method' highlighting the print line.